# Tab Bar Controller items run from the right item

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm developing an iOS App for an Right-to-left language by using Tab Bar. Normally, when I try to start the application, the application will start from the left bar item.

My prblem is, I'm trying to let the application start from the right bar item.

I mean, for example, there are 4 items in the application, like [1 - 2 - 3 - 4]. When I run the application, it will open item "1". But, I'm trying to let the application run by opening item "4".

I'm using Xcode 6 and Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab bars will, by default, set the first item as the selected one unless you specify otherwise (either in code or in your storyboard / xib file). You can programmatically select the current item on your tab bar. For example:

```
[tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4]];
```

Just keep in mind that the indices start at 0 so the indices are 0-1-2-3 and not 1-2-3-4.